# Pitcher Game in Java

Tags: java

I am developing a code for the pitcher game. Need small help to find the number of combinations which are possible to find moves which will lead to a goal state
I have 3 pitchers with capacity 20 15 5 and the goal is that one of the pitcher should have the value 10. Initially only the first pitcher is full. (i.e the start state is 20 0 0)
I wish to use BFS to find if such a goal is possible. Can anyone suggest me what how many total moves should I try if there is no solution possible?

Example
    capacity 10 7 3 goal 1

```
10 0 0
3 7 0
3 4 3
6 4 0
**3 7 0**
6 1 3 --> Goal
```

Now suppose I have goal as 11 which is clearly not possible, then how many moves should I try in all to guarantee that a solution is not possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to find the solution via a search, you would have to try every possible move, *excluding states that have already occurred*, to guarantee that a solution is not possible.

Comment: Is there a mathematical formula to find exactly how many possible moves are going to be there ?